# A question about formatting syntax in `yaml`

Tags: yaml, hydra

I'm trying to understand some yaml syntax related to using hydra in a machine learning approach. So given the following, extracted from the original [github repo](https://github.com/txie-93/cdvae):

```
datamodule:
  _target_: cdvae.pl_data.datamodule.CrystDataModule

  datasets:
    train:
      _target_: cdvae.pl_data.dataset.CrystDataset
      name: Formation energy train
      path: ${data.root_path}/train.csv
      prop: ${data.prop}
      niggli: ${data.niggli}
      primitive: ${data.primitive}
      graph_method: ${data.graph_method}
      lattice_scale_method: ${data.lattice_scale_method}
      preprocess_workers: ${data.preprocess_workers}
```

I don't understand what the syntax `${}` stands for in this context. Is that some kind of text formatting? Or is it calling some specific module? Could anybody provide some examples?

EDIT:

Ok, as pointed by @flyx, it seems that the syntax `${}` refers to `hydra` which is indeed part of the project I'm analyzing.

Comment: `${}` is not YAML syntax. YAML reads it as scalar content. Whatever this does is hydra-specific, I suggest to add the relevant tag so that the right people see this. I wouldn't know the correct tag as there seem to be multiple things named `hydra`.

Comment: Many thanks, I've added the tag to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The string `foo: ${bar}` in yaml corresponds roughly to the dict `{"foo": "${bar}"}` in python. This is to say, the dollar-bracket notation `${}` is not given special meaning by the yaml grammar.

[OmegaConf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/), which is the backend used by [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.3/intro/), *does* give special meaning to the dollar-bracket syntax; it is used for "variable interpolation." See [the OmegaConf docs on variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.3_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation).

To summarize briefly, the idea of variable interpolation is that the string `"${bar}"` is a "pointer" to the value with key `bar` that would appear elsewhere in your OmegaConf config object.

Here's a short demo of variable interpolations in action:

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
yaml_data = """
foo: ${bar}
bar: baz
"""
config = OmegaConf.create(yaml_data)
assert config.bar == "baz"
assert config.foo == "baz"  # the ${bar} interpolation points to the "baz" value
```